# Javascript search both name and description

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, search

I have a search bar, currently used for searching "Product name" and "SKU". The search bar use '-' as a unique char to identify that it is a "SKU".

For example, below are the product attributes.

```
SKU: BR-3BA-319-WS
Name: Fit 90-14 AUDI 3-BICYCLES REAR TRUNK MOUNT RACK CARRIER
Year: 1990;1991;1992;1993;1994;1995;1996;1997;1998;1999;2000;2001;2002;2003;2004;2005;2006;2007;2008;2009;2010;2011
```

Currently, I am using the code which is having lots of issue.

Like it cannot find the keyword combinations like these:

```
"1999 audi rack", because 1999 is not in the "Name" but in "Year" 
"AUDI 3-BICYCLES REAR TRUNK MOUNT RACK", because of '-' , it will be define as SKU.
```

My code is this, how could I make the search can search well like above?

Make it able to search in multiple attributes in a better way.

```
$j("#searchBtn2").click(function(){
    var searchText = $j("#productInput2").val();
    if(searchText.indexOf('-')>=0){
        baseURL="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>"+"catalogsearch/advanced/result/?sku="+$j("#productInput2").val();
        window.location = baseURL;
    }else{
        baseURL="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>"+"catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name="+$j("#productInput2").val();
        window.location = baseURL;}
    });
```

- productInput2 is the textbox for keyin the keyword and search.
- baseURL is our website URL.
- searchBtn2 is the search button for trigger the function.
- The code path is baseURL/catalogsearch/advanced/, named result.html

Comment: You can use LIKE clause along with OR operator in SQL query while fetching data.